# trusted_host_patterns behind reverse_proxy

Tags: 8, proxies

I'm trying to run Drupal 8.0.5 on Apache 2.4 behind an Nginx reverse proxy (both on the same host). However, I'm running into problems w.r.t. `trusted_host_patterns`, i.e. I'm getting [`The provided host name is not valid for this server.`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/145286/58028).

In Apache, the HTTP `Host` header doesn't contain target host of the original request but the reverse proxy (since I'm using [`mod_remoteip`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html)). However, I have set up Nginx to pass on the `Host` header value of the original request in the `X-Forwarded-Host` header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header Forwarded          "for=$remote_addr;proto=$scheme";
```

I have also told Drupal that it's running behind a reverse proxy:

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;

/**
 * Specify every reverse proxy IP address in your environment.
 * This setting is required if $settings['reverse_proxy'] is TRUE.
 */
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = ['127.0.0.1'];

/**
 * Set this value if your proxy server sends the client IP in a header
 * other than X-Forwarded-For.
 */
# $settings['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP';

/**
 * Set this value if your proxy server sends the client protocol in a header
 * other than X-Forwarded-Proto.
 */
# $settings['reverse_proxy_proto_header'] = 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO';

/**
 * Set this value if your proxy server sends the client protocol in a header
 * other than X-Forwarded-Host.
 */
# $settings['reverse_proxy_host_header'] = 'X_FORWARDED_HOST';

/**
 * Set this value if your proxy server sends the client protocol in a header
 * other than X-Forwarded-Port.
 */
# $settings['reverse_proxy_port_header'] = 'X_FORWARDED_PORT';

/**
 * Set this value if your proxy server sends the client protocol in a header
 * other than Forwarded.
 */
# $settings['reverse_proxy_forwarded_header'] = 'FORWARDED';
```

Hence I don't understand why the hostname validation still fails. If I disable `mod_remoteip` then both `Host` and `X-Forwarded-Host` contain the original target host, and in that case hostname validation succeeds. It seems that Drupal fails to use `X-Forwarded-Host` instead of `Host`.

Comment: Does the doc block for [this method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!http-foundation!Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetHost/8.2.x) help?

Comment: @Clive: Not really :) I've configured `reverse_proxy_addresses`, so my proxy should be trusted. The comments in `settings.php` indicate that the default value for `reverse_proxy_host_header` is `X-Forwarded-Host`, which I'm setting in Nginx. (Note that my original post had a wrong version of my Nginx configuration, I've fixed that now)