# WSOD "The provided host name is not valid for this server"

Tags: 8, wsod

My Drupal 8 site only works with www. but without it I'm getting a WSOD with the "The provided host name is not valid for this server" error.

I've tried to implement the suggestions from this thread:
[What does "The provided host name is not valid for this server" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean/282202?noredirect=1#comment350668_282202)

Specifically I tried:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www\.example\.com$',
  '^example\.com$'
);

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [];

$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [ '.*' ];
```

Still, site will only work with www

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "The provided host name is not valid for this server" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your domains into the array as per your first example. I.e.

```
    $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www\.yourdomain\.co\.uk$',
  '^yourdomain\.co\.uk$',
);
```

Then clear the caches and the message should go away. It may be that you're missing the comma after your second entry.