# The provided host name is not valid for this server even after updating settings.php

Tags: configuration

I'm running in to the error message
`The provided host name is not valid for this server.`

I found the previous solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean) however even once updating my `settings.php` file I'm continuing the hit this problem.

My two domains are almost identical however the second one includes an `a` at the beginning. Therefore my `two trusted_host_patterns` are exactly the same except that the second one includes an a after the `^`. Is it possible that there is something else I'm missing? Looking in `admin/reports/status` I can see the two domains listed under trusted hosts.

Here's the line:

```
 $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
    '^domain\.com$',
    '^adomain\.com$',
 );
```

Comment: Can you post your setting? Dots need to be escaped with a backlash ..

Comment: @rémy Yep, updated the original post.

Comment: Okey, this will work if you access the page without www.

Comment: Okay, should I add two more rules for when it's `www` first then? I believe most of the time I'm simply typing adomain.com, but maybe it's getting autofilled to have the www

Comment: Yes add the versions with www\., if you do not have set a preferred domain.