# The provided host name is not valid for this server on OVH Web Server

Tags: 8

I'm using an OVH web server, I went to the ftp browser and did add all my files into www. 
I was using Drupal 8 in local.

When I want to go to my website, I've this error:

> The provided host name is not valid for this server.

Comment: Not really, since I've this on settings.php: `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array('^miage-groupe9-webdesign.fr');` and my website is `miage-groupe9-webdesign.fr`

Comment: Check https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/145286/15055 you need to pay attention to the punctuation.

Comment: Even with `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array( '^miage-groupe9-webdesign\.fr$'
);` it does not work. Should I put \ before the - ?

Comment: So there's no www or other subdomain in front? And you flushed cache of course?

Comment: Yes I did flush the cache. And there is http so I dit change and there is still the error `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] =  array('^http://miage-groupe9-webdesign\.fr/');`

Comment: *trusted_host_patterns* is for the domain name, not the protocol used to access it.

Comment: The domain name is : `miage-groupe9-webdesign.fr/`