# "drush updatedb" failes with "The provided host name is not valid for this server"

Tags: drush, 9

I run my site with Drupal 9.1.6 on Strato Webhosting. The site is well accessible via Webbroser either under mydomain.tld or [www.mydomain.tld](http://www.mydomain.tld). I can perform a database update running update.php, but if I try the same with `/opt/RZphp74/bin/php-cli vendor/bin/drush updatedb`, I get this error.

> The provided host name is not valid for this server

Drush version is 10.4.2.

I seem to be able to clear the cache of the site with `/opt/RZphp74/bin/php-cli vendor/bin/drush cc`. At least after some time Drush reports success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The provided host name is not valid for this server" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean)

Comment: No. As I said, settings.php seems well configured and I have no problem accessing the site via Browser. Just with drush I get this errormessage.

Comment: Or does need drush specific settings if it is invoked the way I've described?