# What are the causes of the malfunction (The provided host name is not valid for this server) and how to fix it?

Tags: configuration, installation

My site stopped suddenly, with an error message

> The provided host name is not valid for this server.

And even though I removed

> $settings['trusted_host_patterns']

Completely from the settings file and cleared the cache via Drush

```
drush cache-rebuild
```

also, i tried use this settings:

`$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [ '.*' ]; and $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [];`

but, the site still shows the same error, and i cant access Drupal log or anywhere to detected the problem cause.

Apache settings are also fine, like mentioned in one of the previous experiments [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean)

**What are the causes of this error and how can it be fixed?**

**note:**

1. The site was previously working with trusted_host_patterns settings.
2. my domain name has dash (-), so i used this pattern:

   `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = ['^[domain/-/name]\.com$',  '^www\.[domain/-/name]\.com$', '^www\.[domain\-name]\.com$', '[domain\-name]\.com$', ];`

two week ago, but it stopped working suddenly today, and I removed trusted_host_patterns setting, but it not resolved.

Note:  I checked adding `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [ '.*' ];` and `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [];` either, both don't work.

Comment: All this is fully explained in [What does "The provided host name is not valid for this server" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean). Read the answer!

Comment: I read this, and I removed
`$settings['trusted_host_patterns']`  
Completely because it did not work.

Comment: Deleting a configuration value doesn't magically set a correct value out of the blue. For testing you need at least something like `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [ '.*' ];` - FOR TESTING ONLY, don't do this in production. **Use your real hostname in production**

Comment: @Hudri i checked adding `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [ '.*' ];` and `$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [];` either, both don't work.

Answer (score -2):

i resolved the problem by:

1. in centos:

> /etc/httpd/sites-available/[domain_name].conf
>  <VirtualHost
> [domain_name]:80>
> ServerName www.[domain_name]
> ServerAlias [domain_name]

and, since my domain name has dash, i used this regex:

> [._:-]